# How to use a table as holidays in WorkDay function in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with a list of holidays on my holidays sheet, "Tools". However, running the code below I get "Unable to the get the WorkDay property" when I include the holidaysArray

```
Sub addWorkingdays()
    Dim holidaysArray As Variant
    holidaysArray = Workbooks("Current.xlsm").Worksheets("Tools").Range("A1:A10").Value
    Dim endDate As Date
    daysRemaining = 10
    
    endDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Now, daysRemaining, holidaysArray)
            workingSheet.Cells(N, 4) = CDate(endDate)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't need to make my Range into an array. Workday can take the date range directly.

```
Sub addWorkdingdays()
    Dim endDate As Date
    daysRemaining = 10
    Set holidayRange = Workbooks("Current.xlsm").Worksheets("Tools").Range("A1:A10")
    endDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(Now, daysRemaining, holidayRange)
            workingSheet.Cells(N, 4) = CDate(endDate)
End Sub
```

Comment: In fact, you do not use the range, as you think... You use an array, too. Declaring `holidaysArray As Variant`, it can be an array or a `Range`. Excel guesses what bo be, by the way you are giving it a value. In order to be a `Range`, **it is mandatory to `Set` it**: `Set holidaysRange = Workbooks("Current.xlsm")....`. Otherwise, it loads an array. Not setting it, Excel guessed that you need an array, even if you did not use `.value`. If it works now, you maybe gave a value to `N`, and `Cells(N, 4)` had a meaning, or corrected something else... Is `N` a global variable? If so, it lost its val.

Comment: In order to check what I say above, please add the next code line after `holidaysRange = Workbooks("Current.xlsm")....`: `Debug.Print TypeName(holidaysRange): Stop` 'it returns Variant(). Then use  `Set holidaysRange = Workbooks("Current.xlsm")....` followed by `Debug.Print TypeName(holidaysRange): Stop 'it returns Range, now...

Comment: @FaneDuru the code in the answer was wrong, what ended up working was putting the full Workbooks... A14) in the Worday as a parameter. Your "Set =" made the code more readable and is now in the answer

Comment: The code should work with an array or with a range, too. For the chosen solution, it is good to also declare `holidayRange As Range`. For the array variant, if I remember well, the function requires a 1D array. So, I would also try the previous `Variant` version (only to see if it works) but transposing the column range: `holidayRange = Application.Transpose(Workbooks("Current.xlsm").Worksheets("Tools").Range("A1:A10").Value)` to obtain the necessary `list` (1D array)...